# How to check for a valid URL in Java?

Tags: java, validation, url

What is the best way to check if a URL is valid in Java?

If tried to call `new URL(urlString)` and catch a `MalformedURLException`, but it seems to be happy with anything that begins with `http://`.

I'm not concerned about establishing a connection, just validity.  Is there a method for this?  An annotation in Hibernate Validator?  Should I use a regex?

**Edit:**  Some examples of accepted URLs are `http://***` and `http://my favorite site!`.

Comment: How do you define validity if you're not going to establish a connection?

Comment: Can you give an example of something which isn't a valid URL that the `URL` constructor accepts?

Comment: @mmyers: Validity should be determined by RFCs 2396 and 2732, the ones which define what a URL is.

Comment: What do you mean with *anything that begins with http://* ? Is `http://spaces allowed`  valid?  For instance `http://mylocalmachine` is still valid.

Comment: @uckelman: Just about anything.  "`http://***`" works.  "`http://my favorite site!`" works.  I can't get it to throw an exception (when http:// is at the beginning.)

Comment: This throws an exception: `http://example.com:80#foo/bar`, even though the URL is perfectly valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating URL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Consider using the [Apache Commons UrlValidator class](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html)

```
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
urlValidator.isValid("http://my favorite site!");
```

There are several properties that you can set to control how this class behaves, by default `http`, `https`, and `ftp` are accepted.

Comment: it does not appear to work with newer domains such as .london etc

Comment: how about intranet urls?

Comment: It doesn't validate urls with underscores.

Comment: Does not work with new TLDs and local domain names, e.g. `local`, etc.

Comment: I could not get UrlValidator to work with our wierd intranet top level domain. The common ones like .com, .org, and such works. I am not interested in creating a RegExp for this matter so the `new URL(name).toURI()` become the solution.

Comment: This return false on characters like "é". I know, for english people, you might not care. But there are a lot of characters like that out there and if you want to build something international, you should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 69):

Here is way I tried and found useful,

```
URL u = new URL(name); // this would check for the protocol
u.toURI(); // does the extra checking required for validation of URI
```

Comment: Good one. Using just new URL(name) accepts almost everything. The url.toURI(); is exactly what the developer is looking for - without using other libraries/frameworks!

Comment: This will also not work for malformed URLs such as http:/google.com. I used UrlValidator from Apache Commons.

Comment: This one is really dangerous. I see that there are lots of other articles out there with this example. `URL u = new URL(http://google).toURI();` will not throw an exception.

Comment: @SonuOommen maybe because `new URL(http://google)` is valid^^
we have lot of internal domain in my company like this

Answer (score 8):

I'd love to post this as a comment to [Tendayi Mawushe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230770/27862), but I'm afraid there is not enough space ;)

This is the relevant part from the Apache Commons UrlValidator [source](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html):

```
/**
 * This expression derived/taken from the BNF for URI (RFC2396).
 */
private static final String URL_PATTERN =
        "/^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/";
//         12            3  4          5       6   7        8 9

/**
 * Schema/Protocol (ie. http:, ftp:, file:, etc).
 */
private static final int PARSE_URL_SCHEME = 2;

/**
 * Includes hostname/ip and port number.
 */
private static final int PARSE_URL_AUTHORITY = 4;

private static final int PARSE_URL_PATH = 5;

private static final int PARSE_URL_QUERY = 7;

private static final int PARSE_URL_FRAGMENT = 9;
```

You can easily build your own validator from there.

Answer (score 7):

The most "foolproof" way is to check for the availability of URL:

```
public boolean isURL(String url) {
  try {
     (new java.net.URL(url)).openStream().close();
     return true;
  } catch (Exception ex) { }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually querying a URL may result in a change, action, or tracking. OP wants to check validity without making the query. E.g., maybe this is to store now and execute later, with reasonable assurance it is valid.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite approach, without external libraries:

```
try {
    URI uri = new URI(name);

    // perform checks for scheme, authority, host, etc., based on your requirements

    if ("mailto".equals(uri.getScheme()) {/*Code*/}
    if (uri.getHost() == null) {/*Code*/}

} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't like any of the implementations (because they use a Regex which is an expensive operation, or a library which is an overkill if you only need one method), so I ended up using the java.net.URI class with some extra checks, and limiting the protocols to: http, https, file, ftp, mailto, news, urn.

And yes, catching exceptions can be an expensive operation, but probably not as bad as Regular Expressions:

```
final static Set<String> protocols, protocolsWithHost;

static {
  protocolsWithHost = new HashSet<String>( 
      Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "file", "ftp", "http", "https" } ) 
  );
  protocols = new HashSet<String>( 
      Arrays.asList( new String[]{ "mailto", "news", "urn" } ) 
  );
  protocols.addAll(protocolsWithHost);
}

public static boolean isURI(String str) {
  int colon = str.indexOf(':');
  if (colon < 3)                      return false;

  String proto = str.substring(0, colon).toLowerCase();
  if (!protocols.contains(proto))     return false;

  try {
    URI uri = new URI(str);
    if (protocolsWithHost.contains(proto)) {
      if (uri.getHost() == null)      return false;

      String path = uri.getPath();
      if (path != null) {
        for (int i=path.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if ("?<>:*|\"".indexOf( path.charAt(i) ) > -1)
            return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  } catch ( Exception ex ) {}

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the source code for `URI`, the

```
public URL(URL context, String spec, URLStreamHandler handler)
```

[constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String,%20java.net.URLStreamHandler)) does more validation than the other constructors. You might try that one, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

#### validator package:

There seems to be a [nice package by Yonatan Matalon called UrlUtil](http://matalon.org/search-algorithms/doc/org/matalon/pagerankhits/util/UrlUtil.html). Quoting its API:

```
isValidWebPageAddress(java.lang.String address, boolean validateSyntax, 
                      boolean validateExistance) 
Checks if the given address is a valid web page address.
```

#### Sun's approach - check the network address

Sun's Java site offers [connect attempt as a solution](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2003/tt0422.html) for validating URLs.

#### Other regex code snippets:

There are regex validation attempts at [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/xdk/schemavalidation/Validate.java) and [weberdev.com](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4228.html).

Comment: That code is for checking links, which is a different problem. This question is about the validity of the URL, not whether a connection can be established to it.

Comment: This example is about checking whether the URL is available, not whether it is well-formed.

Comment: Agreed, added other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There is alsow a Function in org.apache.xerces.util.URI

```
isWellFormedAddress(java.lang.String address)
```

Determine whether a string is syntactically capable of representing a valid IPv4 address, IPv6 reference or the domain name of a network host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String urlString){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            url.toURI();
            return Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlString).matches();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```