# URL valid characters. java to validate

Tags: java, url

a string like: 'www.test.com' is good.
a string like: 'www.888.com' is good.
a string like: 'stackoverflow.com' is good. 
a string like: 'GOoGle.Com' is good.

why ?  because those are valid urls. it does not necessarely matter if they have been registered or not.

now bad strings are:

'goog*d\x' 
'manydots...com'

why because you can't register those urls.

if I have a string in java which is supposed to be a good url 
what's the best way to validate it ?

thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for a valid URL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230676/how-to-check-for-a-valid-url-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those examples are **hostnames**. They're not valid URLs in themselves.

Hostnames are made of `.`-separated ‘labels’. Each label must be up to 63 characters of letters, digits and hyphens, but a hyphen must not be the first or last character. It is optional to follow the whole hostname with another dot.

You can match this with a pattern like (assuming case-insensitive):

```
([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])(\.[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])*\.?
```

However this matches strings like `1.2.3.4` as well, which although they technically could be host/domain names will actually act as direct IP addresses. You may want to allow that. If you do, you may also want to allow IPv6 addresses, which are colon-separated hex; when embedded in a URL, they also have square brackets around them.

And then of course there's IDNA. Nowadays, `例え.テスト` is a valid IDNA domain name, corresponding to `xn--r8jz45g.xn--zckzah`. If you want to allow those you'll need some Unicode support.

Summary: it's quite a bit more difficult than you might think. And that's just hostnames. ‘Validating’ a whole URL is even more work. A simple regex isn't going to hack it. Use a pre-existing library.

Answer (score 10):

use [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) from the [Apache Commons library](http://commons.apache.org/validator/). Binary package: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/commons/validator/binaries/commons-validator-1.3.1.zip (zip contains .jar files)

Example of usage (Construct a UrlValidator with valid schemes of "http", and "https"):

```
String[] schemes = {"http","https"}.
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
if (urlValidator.isValid("ftp://foo.bar.com/")) {
   System.out.println("url is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("url is invalid");
}
```

prints "url is invalid"

If instead the default constructor is used.

```
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
if (urlValidator.isValid("ftp://foo.bar.com/")) {
   System.out.println("url is valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("url is invalid");
}
```

prints out "url is valid"

Answer (score -1):

I think that `new URL(yourString)` will do the trick: it is supposed to raise `MalformedURLException` if url is not compliant (actually on java api it says *If the string specifies an unknown protocol*, but you can try it anyway):

```
try
{
   new URL(string);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  //do whatever
}
```

Comment: The problem with URL is, it will attempt to perform a lookup each time :(

Comment: Yes that is true, but how else (except using regex) can you validate an url?

Comment: @Shervin: With Commons UrlValidator.

Comment: @Shervin: with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601780/url-valid-characters-java-to-validate/2601792#2601792

Comment: Again like I said. Those examples must be using regex to check if an url is valid. That is the only way if you don't want to make a connection

Comment: This does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java/5965755#5965755

Answer (score -1):

I also believe you can use the [URL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) in java.net

```
URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
```

The api says 

`public URL(String spec) throws MalformedURLException
Parameters:
spec - the String to parse as a URL. 
Throws: 
MalformedURLException - If the string specifies an unknown protocol.`

So an exception is thrown if the URL is invalid.

Comment: This does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java/5965755#5965755

Answer (score -2):

You can do this kind of "url validation" through [Regular Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

And [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url) is where you can get some good URL regex's (so you don't have to write your own).