# How to Optimally check for URL validity

Tags: java, url

A straightforward way to check for URL validity, is to simply handle a `MalformedURLException` exception:

```
try {
  URL base = new URL(SomeString);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // handles this in some way
}
```

But AFAIK, using exceptions to implement program logic is conceptually incorrect (and perhaps more costly in runtime performance).

On the other hand, I don't know of a Java method that does `isValid(String url)`.

Is there a better way to check URL's string validity ***without*** instantiating a URL object (and handling a `MalformedURLException`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for a valid URL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230676/how-to-check-for-a-valid-url-in-java). Note that not getting a MalformedURLException is no guarantee that the URL is valid.

Comment: @Grodriguez Good catch! But the accepted answer there is not acceptable... See performance considerations below.

Comment: worth noting that the hibernate UrlValidator (org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl) does just catch the exception to ascertain validity.

Comment: Depends on what you consider acceptable :-). Working and slow is better than not working and fast. I'd worry about a proper solution first, then worry about performance only if this proves to be a real bottleneck in your application. For example if after validation the URL will be used to establish a network connection, then the cost of the regex will be absolutely negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, write a regular expression to check it.

[Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-java)

Comment: A regex is *very* expensive. But is it more expensive than exception handling? ("expensive" here refers to performance) +1

Comment: I'm not sure, that would need some testing (would probably be a good SO question on its own). It does seem to be more elegant though.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because after inspecting [the URL Java source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/URL.java.html), I realized that the exception handling may be cheaper. That's because the implementation URL avoids regex. So I think I got all the information that I need, to proceed with a well informed decision.

Answer (score 2):

You can move that functionality to an utility method: `URLUtils.isValid(url)` where you return `false` from `catch`. After that you can switch to another method, if you decide to.

For example you can use [`UrlValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) from commons-validator.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking for the "better method" to which you're referring.

Comment: @spork - and one exists in the 2nd paragraph of my answer

Comment: @Bozho [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) looks great. I'll check that out. +1

Comment: yup. If only the designers of the URL class have moved the parsing logic to a separate `.isValid(..)` method

Comment: @Bozho I just checked [the source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/commons-validator/commons-validator-1.3.1/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.java.html) and they're using regex to perform that the check... I'd better implement that method myself, then. :)