# Source.fromURL not throwing an exception for an invalid URL

Tags: scala

I am attempting to retrieve the sizes various websites whose URL will be passed to my script, but I'm not getting an exception when I pass an invalid URL, instead simply getting a very small page. I'm using `Source.fromURL`, and I get the following results:

```
thisIsClearlyABoggusURLThatCantPossiblyLeadAnyway 1052
www.bbc.co.uk 113871
```

The first one, as it says, shouldn't have anything in it, but it does. My script is as follows:

```
def main( args:Array[String] ){
    val tasks = for(arg <- args) yield future {
        try {
            println(arg + " " + Source.fromURL( attachPrefix(arg) ).length)
        } catch {
            case e : java.net.UnknownHostException => println(arg + " *")
        }
    }

    awaitAll(20000L, tasks: _*)
}

def attachPrefix( url:String ) = url.slice(0, 4) match {
    case "http" => url
    case "www." => "http://" + url
    case _ => "http://www." + url
}
```

Each argument is being passed into the function `attachPrefix` to ensure it has the necessary prefix before being used. This problem has only come about since I started passing the url in as a parameter instead of mapping it onto the `arg`, which is what I was doing earlier with

```
args map attachPrefix
```

What's the difference between the two, and why is my current one giving such behaviour?

Comment: You can use [java's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2230676/298389)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I didn't know about that one :) In this case however, I need it to be in pure Scala.

Comment: `scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://www.thisIsClearlyABoggusURLThatCantPossiblyLeadAnyway")` throws `java.net.UnknownHostException`. I am wondering what your code that retrieves the size is doing exactly? Do you have a `toString` in your code maybe – and are actually retrieving the length of the exception text, maybe...?

Comment: @Hbf, after reading your comment I played around with the code and found out what was causing the problem, but I don't have any idea what it's causing it. I've updated my question with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Source.fromURL(URI)` signature. Creating a `URI` will effectively validate the `URL` as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). However, in this case, the `URL` `http://www.thisIsClearlyABoggusURLThatCantPossiblyLead‌​Anyway` is valid as far as the `URI` is concerned. On the other hand, the `UrlValidator` suggested by om-nom-nom considers it invalid, because the top level domain segment has more than 4 characters which is already out of date. I don't know of any entirely Scala validation libraries or why this would be a requirement, but you could try using a regular expression for validation. For example, this will catch your example, because the top level domain exceeds 6 letters:

```
val re = """^(https?://)?(([\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+: )?[\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([\w!~*'()-]+\.)*([\w^-][\w-]{0,61})?[\w]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/*)|(/+[\w!~*'().;?:@&=+$,%#-]+)+/*)$""".r
re.pattern.matcher("http://google.com").matches // true
re.pattern.matcher("http://www.thisIsClearlyABoggusURLThatCantPossiblyLeadAnyway").matches // false
```