# Variable never used

Tags: java, android, exception

I've this portion of code:

```
/**
 * Checks if the provided URL is valid.
 *
 * @param urlToCheck - The URL to check.
 *
 * @return boolean true if it's valid.
 */
protected boolean isUrlValid( String urlToCheck )
{
    boolean isValid = true;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL( urlToCheck );
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException exception )
    {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a new URL Object, which crashes if the String URL is not valid. This is working, the "problem" is that LINT says I'm not using `url` variable. 
I don't really have to use it, so here's my question:

- Is there any other better approach?
- Can I supress lint checking JUST for this line?

Comment: remove `URL url = `. The warning should go away.

Comment: you can disable lint checks

Comment: You are declaring and initializing the URL in try block, and in the scope of try block, url is never used. So this warning stays.. If you don't want to use url then simply remove that line.

Comment: How about; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230676/how-to-check-for-a-valid-url-in-java. Incidently using exceptions for code flow is always a bad idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see a warning because you are not using the variable and probably wasting memory. If you dont need the variable you can do something like this

```
protected boolean isUrlValid( String urlToCheck )
{
    boolean isValid = true;
    try
    {
        new URL( urlToCheck ); // Notice this
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException exception )
    {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong about doing that, however your variable is not used.

You can change

```
URL url = new URL( urlToCheck );
```

to

```
new URL( urlToCheck );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

> URL url = new URL( urlToCheck );

with something like this:

```
new URL( urlToCheck );
```

This will ensure that you do not have any **unused reference pointing to the URL object**. Thus the compiler will not complain.

Answer (score 0):

In reverse order:

- You can get rid of the warning by not creating a new variable, as others have pointed (use only `new Url(urlToCheck);`

but maybe the better aproach is to:

- use [`URLUtil.isValidUrl(String url)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29) - looking at it's source I see it doesn't create a new url variable which might be better, but it looks like it just checks whether the string starts with a known [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). It's up to you to decide whether this is enough