# Android How Want Use Done button on Keyboard to click button

Tags: android, input, keyboard

In the my app i use editext (i called editext ---> url)
I will that the key "Done" has the action my button 
I have read other ask user but not have understant how to make

Exscuse me for my English

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url){
    v.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    } 
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
    String a= url.toString();
    a = webView.getUrl();
      }
    }); 
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.it");




}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private WebView webView;

private EditText url;
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/reload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/back"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/back"
    android:background="@drawable/refresh"
    android:contentDescription="@string/reload"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh"
    android:text="@string/reload" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/back"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:text="@string/default_url"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/forward"
    android:background="@drawable/Back"
    android:contentDescription="@string/back"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/Back" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/go"
    android:background="@drawable/Forward"
    android:contentDescription="@string/forward"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/Forward" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/Search"
    android:contentDescription="@string/go"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:onClick="go"
    android:src="@drawable/Search"
    android:text="@string/go" />

        <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/url" />
```

Comment: post your xml and code for details.

Comment: i have insert the code please help me

Comment: PLease, post your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the Done button on the keyboard to perform some action. This should do the trick :

```
url.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
              // Your action goes here...
         }
    return false;
                }
});
```

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing what you want is to replace my comment by webView.loadUrl(url.getText().toString()); If so, do not forget to setup proper checks on the validity of the url entered by the user to avoid problems ;)

Comment: how do I check if the url is valid?

Comment: To do it right, check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230676/how-to-check-for-a-valid-url-in-java

Comment: thanks if i use this: String a= url.getText().toString();
                  if (a.contains("www.") == true) {
                  webView.loadUrl(url.getText().toString());
               }
              else  {
                  String search = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+url.getText(); 
                  webView.loadUrl(search);
               }
              }