# How to verify if a String in Java is a valid URL?

Tags: java, url

How to verify if a String in Java is a valid URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating URL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)

Comment: I also looking for this solution. Thanks a lot for this question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can try to create a [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) object out of it. If it is not a proper URL, a [`MalformedURLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) will be thrown.

Comment: Just to be clear, it would only throw a MalformedURLException `if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found`. Unlike, Apache's UrlValidator, no additional validation is performed.

Comment: It actually performs other checks too, e.g. port numbers.

Comment: I quoted that from the javadocs http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html. They don't state any other checks.

Comment: That's what the Javadocs say, however the checks are performed (you can try it yourself, or have a look at the source code if you wish)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will throw a false positive if the url is numerical, such as 192.168.0.1 (without the http://).

Comment: @Tommie "192.168.0.1" (without the http://) is not a valid URL. Creating a `java.net.URL` passing this as parameter fails with `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol`. This is the expected behaviour and is documented as such. No false positive here.

Comment: This test fails for the URL `public static void main(String[] argv) throws MalformedURLException {
  URL url = new URL("http://ProductDetail/2Thumbz, Inc.?source=Admin");
 }` because it **doesn't** throw an exception, despite the comma and space and period.

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be just using URI class for validation. Also commas/dots in this example (after the auth part) should be valid, only the space is not.

Comment: This is an example of using exceptions as flow control and it's generally considered bad, and for good reasons. Suggested reading: http://archive.fo/erYDY

Answer (score 51):

You can use [`UrlValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) from [commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/). It will save you from writing code where the logic flow is guided by catching an exception, which is generally considered a bad practice. In this case, however, I think it's fine to do as others suggested, if you move this functionality to an utility method called `isValidUrl(..)`

Comment: it won't allow underscores in hostname

Answer (score 19):

For **Android** just add this line:

```
boolean isValid = URLUtil.isValidUrl( "your.uri" );
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the scheme/prefix (e.g. "http") is missing (e.g. "stackoverflow.com") and it also doesn't work with the "ftp" scheme/prefix (e.g. "ftp://127.0.0.1").

Comment: Hence the difference between URL and URI

Comment: I also tried the other suggestions (`new URL`/`new URI`) but `URL` doesn't like URLs without scheme (plus it feels like it only checks for the scheme, nothing else) and `URI` seems to return "true", no matter what you throw at it (even "---"). So far I've not found a way to do what op asked that works properly 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 17):

```
public static boolean isValidURL(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        url.toURI();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This checks according to [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html), like `<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>#<fragment>`, but `scheme` must be known by `URL` source code.
These are **not** valid:

- `telnet://melvyl.ucop.edu`
- `news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix`
- `www.google.com`

Comment: Why not just `new URI(urlString)`?

Answer (score 12):

If you program in **Android**, you could use `android.webkit.URLUtil` to test.

```
URLUtil.isHttpUrl(url)
URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(url)
```

Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: This doesnt actually check if its a url it only checks if there is http:// in the beginning, what you need with that is URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)

Comment: Quick heads up that it's called URLUtil ... not URLUtil*S*.

Answer (score 11):

Complementing Bozho answer, to go more practical:

1. Download apache commons [package](http://commons.apache.org/validator/download_validator.cgi) and uncompress it. 
   [image: binaries]
2. Include commons-validator-1.4.0.jar in your java build path.
3. Test it with this sample code ([reference](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/package-summary.html#other.url)):

   ```
   //...your imports

   import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.*; // Import routines package!

   public static void main(String[] args){

   // Get an UrlValidator
   UrlValidator defaultValidator = new UrlValidator(); // default schemes
   if (defaultValidator.isValid("http://www.apache.org")) {
       System.out.println("valid");
   }
   if (!defaultValidator.isValid("http//www.oops.com")) {
       System.out.println("INvalid");
   }

   // Get an UrlValidator with custom schemes
   String[] customSchemes = { "sftp", "scp", "https" };
   UrlValidator customValidator = new UrlValidator(customSchemes);
   if (!customValidator.isValid("http://www.apache.org")) {
       System.out.println("valid");
   }

   // Get an UrlValidator that allows double slashes in the path
   UrlValidator doubleSlashValidator = new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_2_SLASHES);
   if (doubleSlashValidator.isValid("http://www.apache.org//projects")) {
       System.out.println("INvalid");
   }
   ```
4. Run/Debug

Answer (score 3):

This function validates a URL, and returns true (valid URL) or false (invalid URL).

```
public static boolean isURL(String url) {
    try {
        new URL(url);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Be sure to `import java.net.URL;`

Comment: Doesn't fail for `http://ProductDetail/2Thumbz, Inc.?source=Admin` when it should (comma, space, period).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(https://|http://|ftp://|ftps://)(?!-.)[^\\s/\$.?#].[^\\s]*$
```

This is a regex to validate URL for protocols http, https, ftp and ftps.