# Check format of URL

Tags: java

I need a Java code which accepts an URL like `http://www.example.com` and displays whether the format of URL is correct or not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for.

```
public boolean isValidURL(String urlStr) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlStr);
      return true;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's an alternate version:

```
public boolean isValidURI(String uriStr) {
    try {
      URI uri = new URI(uriStr);
      return true;
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use the [java.net.URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class instead.

Comment: no guys it did not worked out can you please provide full code

Comment: @user what didn't work? YOU provide your code and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @adarshr Ok.I understand URL is a subset of URI but in context of this question why did you use URI as well? Won't URL be more specific?

Comment: @Suvarna there's no particular reason. It is just a matter of taste. I was just demonstrating two different ways of solving the same problem.

Comment: The "url" or "uri" local variable is not necessary.

Comment: never use exception in nomral program flow. let thwor the exception is bad

Comment: According to version 1 (`URL`) "stackoverflow.com" is invalid, according to version 2 (`URI`) even nonsense like "---" is valid, so both versions aren't exactly great (unless you have to set up some type of pattern first?). I'd recommend using [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578580/2016165) or Apache's [URLValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078838/2016165) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @adarshr I would say it is best to use the URL class instead of the URI class, the reason for it being that the URL class will mark something like `htt://example.com` as invalid, while URI class will not (which I think was the goal of the question).

```
//if urlStr is htt://example.com return value will be false
public boolean isValidURL(String urlStr) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlStr);
      return true;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```