# UrlValidator is not working for localhost

Tags: java, url-validation

I'm facing an issue that i'm using UrlValidator  in my code.

```
UrlValidator urlValidator = UrlValidator.getInstance();
    if(urlValidator.isValid(url)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( url + "not valid");
    }
 where url i'm passing is 

 [1]: http://localhost:8080/myapp/Education.html
```

.I'm getting IllegalArgumentException n if i'm passing url i.e

```
 [2]: https://www.google.co.in/
```

its working fine.How to make this code working for localhost:8080

Answer (score 31, accepted):

if you take a look at the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html#field_summary) you'll have a hint on how to accept local urls

For example

```
public class Validator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_LOCAL_URLS);
        if (urlValidator.isValid("http://localhost/page.htm")) {
            System.out.println("Valid URL");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid URL");
        }

    }

}
```

it will output

`Valid URL`

Comment: FYI you need to do `new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_LOCAL_URLS)`

Comment: I was hoping he could get to it by himself :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying .But instead of using UrlValidator.getInstance(); i have tried this also "UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_LOCAL_URLS);" but still its not working.

Comment: @AlexGreg : Any comments ?

Comment: yes..what is the condition in the if? if url is valid then you throw an IllegalArgumentException??

tested locally in it worked btw

Comment: But my URL is http://localhost:8080/myapp/Education.html not http://localhost/myapp/Education.html. When i'm passing the URL :-http://localhost/myapp/Education.html not works fine. Actually i have added it into pom.xml file

Comment: this is beacause you are using apache-tomcat on port 8080

Comment: Exactly Alex. So what should be the best approach to overcome with problem. I need it to make this url pass.

Comment: what about using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1600333/3548826) as an alternative to validate URLs?

Comment: @AlexGreg Not Working out :(