# What is a good regular expression to match a Custom URL?

Tags: java

I need to regularize url with many cases in java.

- custom1://www.test.com:6666/path1/path2
- custom2://www.test.com/path1/path2
- custom3://www.test.com
- [www.test.com:6666](http://www.test.com:6666)
- [www.test.com:666](http://www.test.com:666)

if this case, what can i use regex..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `custom URL` first of all this is not a clear statement, you should be more clear, in normal case `^(https?|chrome):\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*$` this regex string should get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

for matching only URLs using regular expressions, you can use the regex above

```
String regex = "((http|https)://)(www.)?"
              + "[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]"
              + "{2,256}\\.[a-z]"
              + "{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%"
              + "._\\+~#?&//=]*)";
```

I found this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-an-url-is-valid-or-not-using-regular-expression/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work just modified little from amireza's answer to add custom also after https or http

```
String regex = "(http|https)"
          + "[a-zA-Z0-9]"
          + "(://)(www.)?"
          + "[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]"
          + "{2,256}\\.[a-z]"
          + "{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%"
          + "._\\+~#?&//=]*)";
```